# Studying if/else vs if/if statement

Tags: java

I was trying to write a code where all the 0s will be moved to the right of the array. I just used a left and a right pointer.

```
 public class Solution {
      public int[] moveZero(int[] array) {
        // Write your solution here
        if (array.length==0) {
          return array;
        }
        int left=0;
        int right=array.length-1;
        while (left<=right) {
          if (array[left]!=0) {
            left+=1;
          } 
          if (array[right]==0) {
            right-=1;
          } else {
            int temp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[right];
            array[right] = temp;
            left+=1;
            right-=1;
          }
        }
        return array; 
      }
    }
```

I know here I should use the if/else if instead of if/if, that's why I have the index out of the bound error. But I don't understand why? If I have the if/if statement, what's the difference does that make rather than using if/else if in this question?

Comment: `if`/`else` means only one branch can execute; if there are two separate `if` statements then both of their blocks can both execute (if both conditions are true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (condition1) {
   a();
} else if (condition2) {
   b();
} else {
   c();
}
```

means the same as

```
if (condition1) {
    a();
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        b();
    } else {
        c();
    }
}
```

So `else if` is just shorthand for an `else` with an `if` inside.

To understand why your code throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, the easiest way is stepping through the code in a debugger (consult the documentation of your development environment for how to do this).

Alternatively, you can pretend you are a computer, and execute the program with pen and paper to figure out where your program goes off the rails. However, using a debugger is easier once you know how to use one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reason to use if/else instead of if/if, they both have their place. In an if/if statement, if the second `if` statement relies on the previous being false, then it should be converted to an if/else statement. If the `else` statement in an if/else statement has nothing to do with the `if` statement before it, then it should be converted into two separate if statements.

As an example of when to use an if/else statement (to do the same thing yours does):

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] moveZero(int[] inputArray) {
        int[] outputArray = new int[inputArray.length];

        int left = 0;
        int right = inputArray.length - 1;

        for (int num : inputArray) {
            if (num == 0) {
                outputArray[right] = num;

                right --;
            } else {
                outputArray[left] = num;

                left ++;
            }
        }

        return outputArray;
    }
}
```